# iframe not sizing properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, safari

I have an `iframe` element which sizes properly in Safari 5.1.5, but not in Chrome.

The CSS for this element is:

```
iframe {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="foo" height="80%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

In Safari, the element looks as expected, like this:

[image: Safari snapshot]

If I resize the browser, the `iframe` is resized.

In Chrome, the element looks much shortened, compared with the Safari result:

[image]

Also, resizing the browser window does not change the size of the `iframe` element.

Is there something I'm missing with my `iframe` setup, which Chrome doesn't like? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Does the parent element of the iFrame have a specified height?

Comment: Maybe, and I might be completely off here, chrome takes 80% of 80%, because you specify the size both in the iframe and in the css?

Comment: if you're using an html5 doctype remove marginheight,marginwidth,and scrolling, these are not supported in html5 http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: The parent height is the height of the browser window. I am using HTML 4 DOCTYPE. If Chrome is taking 80% of 80%, its width would be narrower than Safari's, so that seems like a wrong guess. Anyone else?

Answer (score -1):

I think i found the solution here, was having the same problem on both Chrome and Firefox on Mac.

I wrapped my iframe inside a DIV and added the parameters "display:block;" and also "position:absolute" to both the div and also the iframe tags. I think those two where the culprits. (Also added additional webkit FS for iPad)

works like a charm!